# Spring Boot application failed to start as AWS Lambda with java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kotlin, aws-lambda

Help!

Spring boot application failed to start as AWS Lambda with following error.
With mostly standard dependencies such as  spring-boot-start-data-jpa

It compiles and runs fine locally. Anyone recognize this? and how can one debug on aws lambda?

```
Error loading class com.api.locations.Handler: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-2147483648,-2147483648"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationMetadataLoader$PropertiesAutoConfigurationMetadata.getInteger(AutoConfigurationMetadataLoader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.access$000(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.lambda$getInPriorityOrder$0(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:62)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:360)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:234)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInPriorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.sortAutoConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:461)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:881)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:804)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:774)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:171)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:77)
    at com.api.locations.Handler.<clinit>(Handler.kt:123)
    ... 2 more
```

Here's the handler for aws, its written in kotlin:
One for the springboot application it self, the other class if the handler to handle AWS triggers:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.api.locations","com.api.core"])
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages =["com.api.core.entity"])
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = ["com.api.core.repository"])
class LocationsDriver : SpringBootServletInitializer() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            SpringApplication.run(LocationsDriver::class.java1, *args)
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The AWS server-less main entry point that is called when function is triggered.
 */
@RestController
class Handler : RequestStreamHandler {

    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java1)
        private var handler: SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse>? = null

        init {
            try {
                handler =
                    SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(LocationsDriver::class.java1)
            } catch (e: ContainerInitializationException) {

                e.printStackTrace()
                logger.error(e.message)

                // Re-throw exception to force a cold start
                throw RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e)
            }
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun handleRequest(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream, context: Context) {

        try {
            handler!!.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context)
        } catch (e: ContainerInitializationException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            logger.error(e.message)
        } finally {
            outputStream.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error is: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-2147483648,-2147483648"`. Are your input data same locally and at AWS?

Comment: No, I've never manually inserted any integers like "-2147483648,-2147483648" in the code anywhere.

this seems to be related to springframework.boot.autoconfigure trying to generate metadata by it self?

Comment: @Valeriy What do you mean by input data? can you explain?